# Countdown timer in vue3 composition API / script setup

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is suppose to be a respawn countdown timer for the bosses in my game. I have this object that has individual unix-formatted timestamp, I need to make the function that displays a countdown timer.

my code:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

function convertUnixtoReadable(time: number) {

    const Countdown = new Date(time * 1000).getTime() //2019-12-9 10:30:15
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = Countdown - now;

    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    if (now > Countdown) {
        return ("alive")
    } else {
        return (days + "d " + hours + "h "
            + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ")
    }
}

</script>
```

and my template:

```
       <div v-for="i in MVPTimer.value" :key="i" class="mvp">
         <div class="mvp-info">
            {{ i.mobname }} - 
            {{ convertUnixtoReadable(i.respawntime) }}
          </div>
        </div>
```

Currently it works. it displays if the 'monster' is alive, or the 'time' remaining for it to respawn. but it doesn't "count down" I know I need a setInterval or computed... or both? I'd be able to do this if I were to use options API; but I'd rather practice script setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a vue3 way of doing it with the reactive store state.

```
//store.js
import { reactive, readonly } from 'vue'

const state = reactive({
  countdownPaused: false
})

function toggleCountdownPlayPause() {
  state.countdownPaused = !state.countdownPaused
}

export const store = readonly({
  state,
  toggleCountdownPlayPause
})

//main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import store from './store'
import App from './App.vue'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(store)
app.config.globalProperties.$store=store
app.mount("#app")
// components/Timer.vue
<template>
  <b>
    <span>{{ cowntdown }}</span>
  </b>
</template>
<script>
import store from '../../store'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      store,
      timerCountdown: 120,
      timeout: null
    }
  },
  watch: {
    paused(isPaused) {
      if (!isPaused) {
        this.timerCountdown--
      } else {
        clearTimeout(this.timeout)
      }
    },
    timerCount: {
      handler(value) {
        if (value > 0 && !this.paused) {
          this.timeout = setTimeout(() => this.timerCountdown--, 1000)
        }
      },
      immediate: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    paused() {
      return store.state.countdownPaused
    },
    formattedCountdown() {
        const minutes = Math.floor(this.timerCount / 60) > 0 ? Math.floor(this.timerCount / 60 ) : "00"
        const seconds = this.timerCount % 60 > 9 ? this.timerCount % 60 : "0" + [this.timerCount % 60]
        return `${minutes}:${seconds}`
    }
  }
</script>
// components/TimerPlayPauseButton.vue
<template>
  <button :class="{'paused':paused}" @click="togglePlayPause"></button>
  </template>
  <script>
  import { store } from '../../store'
 
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        store,
        paused: store.state.countdownPaused
      }
    },
    methods: {
      togglePlayPause(e) {
        this.store.toggleCountdownPlayPause()
      }
    }
  }
</script>
<style>
.paused:after {
  content: "ll"
}
//App.vue
<template><div><timer /><timer-play-pause-button /></div></template>
<script>
import Timer from './components/Timer.vue'
import TimerPlayPauseButton from './components/TimerPlayPauseButton.vue'

export default {
   components: {
     'timer': Timer,
     'timer-play-pause-button': TimerPlayPauseButton
   }
}
```